# Export/Import all data between 2 magento website

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have 2 magento sites, let's name them A and B, I want to export all data from A to B. I know that there are many tutorials about this, but most of them are just about how to import/export products and categories, while the data I want to import includes: categories, products, products' images, customers, orders and invoices. In this case I'm too afraid that if I export/import them individually, I won't be able to make them associate with each other.

So my idea is export A's data table, then import them to B (B is an empty magento site), but those tables' relations don't let me do it.

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
your are right, for complete your task essay you just take export catalog,  customer and all sales tables only and import in new magento database and first you need to remove these all table in your new magento database.

It's really successful to you, if your both magento sites on same version then no issue you face it, if not same you need to export data by csv or then you import all data and also you will be use some modules.

if you want product images also copy your media folder in your new site, and only catalog,  customer and all sales tables not copy or move to other.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import everything, then in my opinion, the simplest solution to do this is to create a compressed backup of public_html folder of your A site, export its mysql database and them upload both things to site "B".
But you'll have to edit the database file and input the username and password of site "B".
Hope this helps.